# how we get Message Read/seen Acknowledgment to Sender in smack or in xmpp from android

Tags: android, xmpp

How we get Message Read/Seen  Acknowledgement  in smack or in XMPP from Android,
1. Single Tick Working(When User Send Message then server give Acknowledgement)
2. Double Tick Working (When Message Send to Receiver Device but receiver not Seen Message)

but when receiver Read/Seen Message how we send Acknowledgement to Sender?

Comment: What have you tried? Please share.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MessageEventNotificationListener and MessageEventManager. 
1) Every message start with single tick.
2) When message is delivered and receiving user sent delivered notification to sender. Sender side change from single tick to double tick 
3) When receiving user read this message, this user sent displayed notifications to sender. Sender side change from double tick to blue double tick.Please review smack [javadoc](https://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.2.0/javadoc/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ***MessageEventManager***. Instantiate it as

`messageEventManager = MessageEventManager.getInstanceFor(connection);`

At the **SENDER** side, send a seen/displayed event as

`messageEventManager.sendDisplayedNotification(to, messageID);`

where `to` is JID to whom you have to send this event and `messageID` is the id of the message for which you are sending this event.

Now at the RECEIVER side register a listner like below:

`messageEventManager.addMessageEventNotificationListener(messageEventNotificationListener);`

```
MessageEventNotificationListener messageEventNotificationListener = new MessageEventNotificationListener() {
    @Override
    public void deliveredNotification(Jid from, String packetID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void displayedNotification(Jid from, String packetID) {
      System.out.println("HERE packetID IS THE MESSAGE ID FOR WHICH YOU RECEIVED SEEN/DISPLAYED EVENT AND YOU CAN SET STATUS FOR THAT MESSAGE");
    }

    @Override
    public void composingNotification(Jid from, String packetID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void offlineNotification(Jid from, String packetID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void cancelledNotification(Jid from, String packetID) {

    }
};
```

Comment: add some context to explain how your answer will solve problem, that will really help the community in long run

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ArunVinoth 
I edited my answer